# How i can get value of specific cell if row is checked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I have an HTML table. I need to get specific cell value if column is checked! For each row I have a checkBox.

```
<table id="tabellaOrdinaFarmaci" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Codice Farmaco</th>
                    <th>Nome Farmaco</th>
                    <th>Quantità </th>
                    <th>Quantità di alert</th>
                    <th>Stato</th>
                    <th>Quantità da ordinare</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($query as $row):
                $quantitaDaOrdinare = $row->alert - $row->quantita;
                if ($quantitaDaOrdinare > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <tr id="<?php echo $row->aic; ?>" > 
                        <td ><?php echo $row->aic; ?></td>
                        <td name="nomeFarmac"o><?php echo $row->denominazione ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->quantita; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->alert; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->stato; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control auto" name="codiceFarmaco" value="<?php echo $quantitaDaOrdinare ?>"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>   <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" value="<?php echo$row->aic; ?> ">
                            </label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                } else {

                }
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </tbody>
```

I need (using javascript or jquery) to get, if a button is clicked, every value of cell that have name="nomeFarmaco" for every row that is checked! I try to call this function whe

```
function getValue(){
     var nome = $('input[name="checkBox"]:checked').map(function() {
                            return $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('name="nomeFarmaco').val();
                        }).get();
return nome;}
```

but nome is an empty array! any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: which cell text you want to get??

Comment: the cell that have name="nomeFarmaco"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a custom attribute for the check box and set the value in this attribute.
Like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" value="<?php echo$row->aic; ?> " customattr="<?php echo $row->denominazione ?>">
```

And you javascript function will be :

```
function getValue(){
    var nome = $('input[name="checkBox"]:checked').attr('customattr');
    return nome;
  }
```

Comment: checkbox have another attribute that i use :D

Comment: for get attribute of checkbox I use this    var aicFarmaco = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
                        return $(el).val();
                    }).get(); but now I need get text of specific cell!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is typo?

```
<td name="nomeFarmac"o><?php echo $row->denominazione ?></td>
```

Change it to:

```
<td name="nomeFarmaco"><?php echo $row->denominazione ?></td>
```

And you are targetting a `<td>` and `.val()` won't work. Should be `.text()`

```
var name = [];
$('input[name="checkBox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        name.push($(this).parent().parent().siblings('td[name="nomeFarmaco"]').text());
    } else {
        var index = name.indexOf(name);
        name.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: In this way array is empty!

Comment: @ermanno.tedeschi you can't use `.map()` directly, you need to create the values as an array then use `.map()`.

Comment: Ok but I need to get all text when I click on external button!